# Pandas split dataframe by sessions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got the next DataFrame:

| id | sec |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 45 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 176 |
| 1 | 19 |
| 1 | 876 |
| 3 | 123 |

I want to split it to groups by id by sessions, or create multiple dataframes of this sessions. Like I want to have sessions of each id (session is When more than 30 seconds have passed between user actions)

For example:
sessions for id 1: [45, 19], [876]

I tried gruopby and cat, but I have no idea how to implement this

Comment: can you provied desired output of your example fully?

Comment: I don't have a certain example of an output. Format doesn't really matter a lot. I just need the way to split dataframe on user sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify the session you can use:

```
df['session'] = (df.sort_values(by=['id', 'sec'])
                   .groupby('id')['sec']
                   .apply(lambda s: s.diff().gt(30).cumsum().add(1))
                )
```

Output:

```
   id  sec  session
0   1   45        1
1   2    1        1
2   3  176        2
3   1   19        1
4   1  876        2
5   3  123        1
```